# Inheritance and constructors. Self used before super.init

Tags: swift, class, init

I am new at inheritance in swift and i'd like to understand how to create constructors in the best way. 
I get an error `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'Base'`

```
class Base{
    var id:String
    var link:String

    convenience init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        guard let id = json["id"] as? String,
            let link = json["link"] as? String else{
                print("Failed Base Class Init!")
                return nil
        }
        self.init(id: id, link: link)
    }

    init(id: String, link: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.link = link
    }
}

class Image: Base{
    func addImageToView(imageView: UIImageView){
        Alamofire.request(self.link).responseImage { response in
            if let img = response.result.value {
                imageView.image = img
            }
        }
    }
}

class Gallery:Base{
    var images:[Image] = []

    init?(json: [String: Any]){
        super.init(json: json) // Here i get <- Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'Base'
        guard let tab = json["images"] as? [[String:Any]] else{
            print("Failed Gallery Image Init!")
            return nil
        }
        images = tab.compactMap{return Image(json: $0)}
    }
}
```

How to do so that my class gallery creates a table of images from json and also initializes the id and link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `init?(json` (also) a designated initializer

```
init?(json: [String: Any]) {
    guard let id = json["id"] as? String,
        let link = json["link"] as? String else{
            print("Failed Base Class Init!")
            return nil
    }
    self.id = id
    self.link = link
}
```

And override it in the subclass

```
override init?(json: [String: Any]) {
  super.init(json: json) 
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job i expected :)